# Switching to RC5: more than one component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm getting an error while trying to switch to the latest RC5, and I can't figure out what it means:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
More than one component: DeviceComponent,OtherComponent ("
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        [ERROR ->]<device *ngIf="authService.authenticated"></device>
    </div>
```

It strangely complains at this html.

#### platform.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { PlatformComponent }   from './platform.component';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {IncrementIndexPipe} from '../../pipes/incrementIndex';
import { TruncatePipe} from '../../pipes/truncate';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './platform.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TruncatePipe, IncrementIndexPipe],
    imports:      [BrowserModule,
                   HttpModule,
                   RouterModule,
                   FormsModule,
                   routing],
    bootstrap:    [PlatformComponent],
    providers:    [AuthService, CookieService, appRoutingProviders]
})
export class PlatformModule {}
```

I also keep getting:

```
platform-browser.umd.js:937 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
```

Comment: can you please some more code and the code in app.module.ts

Comment: add your all components in *declarations* pipes are not required to be added over here put *PlatformComponent* also in *declarations*

Comment: @rashfmnb it is already used for bootstrap?

Comment: do you have two root components with the same selector in your page or  two @Component() decorators on the same class.

Comment: @rashfmnb I think I had, I made them all unique (they were just copied I think from my-app), but it does not chance the `No provider for Router`. But I don't get the initial error anymore...

Comment: I think it has to do with making sure the old RouteConfig etc from @angular2/router-deprecated completely disappears from the app.

Comment: what version of router you are using i am using  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1"

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

```
platform-browser.umd.js:937 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
```

I removed all old @angular2/router-deprecated

To solve the "more than one component" error, like @rashfmnb suggests, (1) remove all double @Component decorators (not in my case) and (2) delete duplicate "selector" tags in the @Component decorators. This was **not** an issue is in the previous angular2 versions.